# How to download videos from cisco webex browser viewer?

Tags: video-streaming, file-download, file-conversion

My university streams lectures using Cisco webex and then uploads a link for every single lecture so we can see the recorded video like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8MJy.jpg

There is no way to download the recordings using cisco's site (the section recordings is empity), so i was wondering if i could manually download them or create a program to do so. I don't know anything about video streaming so i wouldn't know where to start.
In the imgur file there's a picture of the network tab if that can help.
Thank you